# Error to start mysql in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

```
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
7:43:04 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
```

I could not able start mysql in xampp please help

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you use skype as they will share the same port. Change skype settings or remove it and try again. I can't remember the port number. I think its 80.

You cannot change port settings in modern skypes so uninstall.

It could be other applications also.

You can make xampp listen on another port but this beyond me

Comment: am not installed skype in my system

Comment: Okay. I can't be too much help here just knew about the skype thing.

Comment: Actually MySQL is generally on port 3306. Do you perhaps have another instance of MySQL running?

Comment: your correct about mysql. Apache running on port 80